# Use fixed Background Image in UINavigationController among multiple views in iOS?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, segue, uicontainerview

I want to use the same background image for the whole app, so I created a normal `UIViewController` with `UIImageView` and `UIContainerView` which contains a navigation controller. Then I set all ViewController's background color to Clear Color Here's my storyboard:

[image: my storyboard]

But when I click the button, the segue between them have some black alpha background. See this GIF:

[image: GIF]

So is there any better way to achieve this? Or how can I solve this? Thanks!

Comment: Have you used this  [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName.png"]]]

Comment: @Jaideep I want the background keep still even the view have changed (without moving) (that GIF is what I want to achieve)

Comment: What do you mean by "black alpha background"? I see a vertical line that separates the view controllers, but everything else may just be a video compression artifact.

Comment: @NRitH yes I do not want that vertical line to display on screen. And everything else is not video compression artefact, it really just display like that...

Comment: Interesting. I wonder whether you can add a custom interactive animation to do that; I don't see anywhere to change the look of the view controllers during transition.

Comment: @NRitH so is there any custom left to right segue? I can't find one, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to subclass UINavigationController and in your CustomNavController viewDidLoad:

- set your UINavigationBar transparent (this might be what you want too)

  ```
  self.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
  self.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
  ```
- set your background to fill the navigation controller view

  ```
  let image = UIImage(named: "background")
  let bgImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height))
  bgImageView.image = image
  self.view.insertSubview(bgImageView, at: 0)
  ```